# Bitcoin Core GUI gettransaction implementation

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, api, electrum, unconfirmed-transactions

The cli users have the option to "getrawtransaction *txid* true" in order to find valuable information about a transaction that could be theirs. This is a very powerful api call that effectively eliminates the need of an electrum server if someone wants to check his tx sent to coldstorage or a mobile wallet.

Do you think there would be any consensus in adding such a feature to the Bitcoin Core GUI? Something like Help -> Verify external txid. This would greatly increase the use of Bitcoin core for the ease of validating a transaction.

Comment: That RPC is a wallet RPC, so it only works for transactions that are in your own wallet.

Comment: I used that rpc from my full node and verified a random transaction on the blockchain. The output of that command was the inputs of the tx and the outputs and number of confirmations and other info. So that is definitely from outside of the local wallet. Maybe I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Perhaps you used `getrawtransaction` (which is a node RPC) instead of `gettransaction` (which is a wallet RPC)?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. Getrawtransaction. Should I edit the question to remove confusion?

Comment: Yes - though perhaps this is better as a feature request than an SE question. Note that it will only work when txindex is enabled. If it's about your own transactions anyway, why not import the relevant addresses/scripts into the wallet as watch-only?

Comment: I wanted to ask here first before making a feature request. Wanted to make sure its not a stupid request. Regarding importing watch only wallet those are extra steps users could just refuse to do or too difficult to import from HW.